# How to search for images/png/jpeg/any other types in the memory of a program and display it?

Tags: c++, windows, reverse-engineering

Well, lately I [have found a very interesting article](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/onlinegames.pdf) about Map Hacks in online games.

After reading it I read they used a memory scanner to look for images in the memory.

How would they accomplish such a program, is there a solution for this freely available?

if not how would I code it in C++? How can I know a piece of memory is an "image"?

I can load my own DLL into the process so that shouldn't be a big issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions:

A memory scanner uses OS apis to query memory from another process and perform searches for patterns or differences. A great tool for this is cheat engine.

The tool mentioned in the article visualizes the memory by coloring pixels according to the value of the bytes in memory. The alignment still needs to be done manually and could be very time consuming. I don't think the mentioned program was ever released.

The main problem is that you can't know that a particular piece of memory is supposed to be a map. Any big regular structure could look like one when colorized and aligned. Finding the actual piece of memory you are looking for is very hard.

---

Additional Info:

A property map in a game is very dynamic. If units or something moves the visibility has to update. So the actual format of a map like this is most likely a binary bitmap with no specific image format (png,jpg,...).

I personally find the approach to look for a map structure in memory is a very inefficient and time consuming approach. It's beatuful to show to people that have no idea about reverse engineering, but to me seems very impractical. The approach which is best totally depends on the game and your creativity.

I hope I can help you with the following example how I made a map hack for starcraft 2.

My idea was to load up a replay of a game, where I had full view of the map and find the difference to loading up a normal game where my vision is restricted. I switched a couple of times between replay and normal game and could indeed find a state variable that was 0 on normal game and 1 on replay (a common tool for finding memory like this is cheat engine).

Next I loaded the game up in a debugger and put a memory access breakpoint on this state variable. Now when loading up a normal game I would change the value when it is accessed while the map was loading. Through some trial and error I was able to find the correct location that was responsible for revealing the minimap and real map. The only task left was to create a dll that detours the code location and make sure the map is always revealed on every mapload.

Answer (score 2):

Reply to typ1232: You mention that it's hard and impractical to find the map structure in memory. Heres a method I have had great success with: Load up a map in any game with fog of war, like StarCraft 2. Take a dump of the memory and save it. Send out troops/units and reveal as much of the previously undiscovered map and take another memory dump. Compare the two dumps and look closer at the areas in memory where there are a high frequency of changes. This is likely to be where the map is stored.

Sorry if I'm doing it wrong, new to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Ah welcome to stack overflow! This is where you should place a comment, but as long as I remember you cannot comment when you are new, and it is kind of an answer on its own, and a bit more practical. Extending your answer on how to accomplish such tasks, for example, with what software do I compare the dumps? and we have to keep in mind that the location can change of the map memory (probably `new` equivalent to C++ is used to allocate the memory)

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit broader answer to the subject of "finding data" but there are binary analysis tools out there. For example, [..cantor.dust..](https://sites.google.com/site/xxcantorxdustxx/about) is a binary visualization tool (though its only in beta the idea remains the same). You can search for different patterns within a memory dump for "images" or structures. Youtube cantor dust and the creator did a presentation at DerbyCon of how he used it to find EFI structures to recreate an exploit of a PNG parser at the EFI level.

I also think the saving two memory states of visible map vs limited visibility map and search for the changes is viable, if not the best option, I just am trying to point out an alternative.